# rails3 app stopped working when the first access on mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, ruby-on-rails-3

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2012-01-21 12:47:45] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-01-21 12:47:45] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2011-10-30) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]
[2012-01-21 12:47:45] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1612 port=3000
[FATAL] failed to allocate memory
```

I added `gem 'mysql2'` to the Gemfile and use `mysql2` adapter in `database.yml`.

The app can start , but when I access `http://localhost:3000`, I got this error:

```
[FATAL] failed to allocate memory
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056157/mac-osx-lion-and-ruby-fatal-failed-to-allocate-memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution at last is uninstall mysql-connector-c, reinstall mysql. and everything works fine now.